# How to change dataframe R column from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD without returning NAs

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe that looks like this (see picture below). I want to change the date from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD but for some reason it returns "NA" values! I think it has to do with the time values behind the date (I do not need those values).[image]

The code I used was this (supposing DF is the data frame)

````
DF[,1] <- as.Date(DF[,1] , format = "%d-%m-%Y")```
````

Comment: The format you show in the picture has slashes `/`, but the format string you use has dashes `-`. Try `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`

Answer (score 0):

Gregor Thomas gave me the answer: The format you show in the picture has slashes /, but the format string you use has dashes -. Try format = "%d/%m/%Y"